# What causes unknown property attribute 'class' with fortify xcodebuild (Objective-C)?

Tags: objective-c, xcodebuild, sourceanalyser

I have an iOS project that I want to run fortify on. Building it with xcodebuild works fine and has for years. Building it with sourceanalyzer xcodebuild fails.

Command to build that actually works:

```
xcodebuild
```

Command that fails

```
sourceanalyzer -b MobuyleUniversaliOS -debug-verbose -logfile fortify-build.log xcodebuild
```

This happens with all sorts of references to NS* classes until finally sourceanalyzer gives up and moves to the next files, which has the same problem. Here's a sample of the error output:

```
In file included from <built-in>:359:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from myproject/MobuyleUniversal-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:43:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly) BOOL supportsSecureCoding;
           ^
In file included from <built-in>:359:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from myproject/MobuyleUniversal-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:38:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSItemProvider.h:36:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSItemProvider.h:41:71: error: property has a previous declaration
@property (NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;
                                                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSItemProvider.h:36:78: note: property declared here
@property (class, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;
                                                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSItemProvider.h:60:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;
           ^
In file included from <built-in>:359:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from myproject/MobuyleUniversal-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:290:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly) const NSStringEncoding *availableStringEncodings;
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:296:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly) NSStringEncoding defaultCStringEncoding;    // Should be rarely used
           ^
In file included from <built-in>:359:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from myproject/MobuyleUniversal-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:11:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSNotification.h:44:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly, strong) NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter;
           ^
In file included from <built-in>:359:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from myproject/MobuyleUniversal-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:12:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:32:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly, strong) NSBundle *mainBundle;
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:43:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSBundle *> *allBundles;
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:44:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSBundle *> *allFrameworks;
           ^
In file included from <built-in>:359:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from myproject/MobuyleUniversal-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCalendar.h:7:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDate.h:45:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly) NSTimeInterval timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDate.h:57:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSDate *distantFuture;
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDate.h:58:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSDate *distantPast;
           ^
In file included from <built-in>:359:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from myproject/MobuyleUniversal-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCalendar.h:100:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSCalendar *currentCalendar;                                  // user's preferred calendar
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCalendar.h:101:12: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (class, readonly, strong) NSCalendar *autoupdatingCurrentCalendar API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5), ios(2.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0)); // tracks changes to user's preferred calendar identifier
           ^
In file included from <built-in>:359:
In file included from <command line>:3:
In file included from myproject/MobuyleUniversal-Prefix.pch:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:15:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCharacterSet.h:20:22: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (readonly, class, copy) NSCharacterSet *controlCharacterSet;
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCharacterSet.h:21:22: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (readonly, class, copy) NSCharacterSet *whitespaceCharacterSet;
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCharacterSet.h:22:22: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (readonly, class, copy) NSCharacterSet *whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet;
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSCharacterSet.h:23:22: error: unknown property attribute 'class'
@property (readonly, class, copy) NSCharacterSet *decimalDigitCharacterSet;
                     ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

'class' properties were added to Objective-C sometime middle to late last year (2016).

My thinking is that fortify/sourceanalyzer (which I've not used) either doesn't support that language feature, or it does and you need a newer version.

Comment: Thanks. I have to go through IT and our security department to get a new version. If/when that fixes it I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @GingerMcMurray I looked briefly to see if there was documentation as to what language version/spec for Objective-C fortify uses, but I couldn't find it. My gut tells me this scenario is the case. Good luck.